# An asymptotic for a simple oscillatory integral

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, wave-equation, oscillatory-integral, dispersive-pde

Consider the oscillatory integral

$$I(\lambda):=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} \psi(x,y) \, \mathrm{e}^{\dot{\imath}\phi(x,y)}dxdy$$
where

1) the phase $\phi$ and amplitude $\psi$ are smooth

2) $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\psi(x,y)=\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}\psi(x,y)=0$

3) $\psi$ and all its derivatives are uniformly bounded

4) there exists a unique point $(x_0,0)$
such that $\phi(x_0,0)=0$, $(\nabla \phi)(x_0,0)=0$ but $|(D^{2}\phi) (x_0,0)|=c\neq 0$.

5)$(\nabla \phi)(x,y)\neq 0$ in the domain $x>0$, $y>0$ BUT the nonstationary phase asymptotic is not useful because the gradient is not uniformly bounded.

How get an asymptotic of this oscillatory integral?

Thanks a lot